# File association using CMD

Tags: file, cmd, associations

What are ways to associate file from cmd?
For example,I  want **`.txt`** file extension to associate with a typical program, through command prompt?
what is the correct file association cmd command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One needs to use `ftype` and `assoc` commands as follows (and note that sequence matters):

```
ftype txtfile="C:\Program Files (x86)\PSPad editor\PSPad.exe" "%1"
assoc .log=txtfile
assoc .txt=txtfile
assoc .wtx=txtfile
```

or

```
ftype TIFImage.Document="C:\Program Files\MSPVIEW.exe" "%1"
assoc .tif=TIFImage.Document
assoc .tiff=TIFImage.Document
```

Note that I haven't `MSPVIEW.exe` installed so I can't approve your `ftype` assignment rightness. In *my Windows* `ftype TIFImage.Document` command output is as follows:

```
TIFImage.Document=%SystemRoot%\System32\rundll32.exe "%ProgramFiles%\Windows Photo Viewer\PhotoViewer.dll", ImageView_Fullscreen %1
```

Answer (score 0):

File association with COMMAND PROMPT (using `.bat` file):

```
REG ADD "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\notepad++.exe\shell\open\command"     /v ""     /t REG_SZ     /d "\"C:\Program Files\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe\" \"%%1\""       /f
::or use --------------->  REG ADD "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shell\open\command"                        /v ""     /t REG_SZ     /d "\"C:\Program Files\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe\" \"%%1\""       /f
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.txt"                 /v "Application"   /t REG_SZ     /d "notepad++.exe"      /f
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.txt\OpenWithList"    /v "g"             /t REG_SZ     /d "notepad++.exe"      /f

ftype txtfile="C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "%%1"      
assoc .txt=txtfile
```

**NOTE! If typing directly in CMD(instead of .bat) then use single % (instead of double %%) and single \ (instead of double \)**

Comment: Windows 10 (and possibly 8): explorer has changed some of it's registry behavior for filetypes in the name of security.  Who knows if this will stay the same, HKCU/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Explorer/FileExts to name at least one. Best get a (command line) tool to do it for you these days unless you are well versed in all versions of the windows registry, and all the secret places microsoft uses to put stuff. Not to mention the restrictions on adminstrator users, they are not like a root user anymore. Many more of the was-"admin" rights are now belonging to "SYSTEM".

Answer (score 0):

The previous suggested solutions are unnecessarily complicated and risky. Just right click on the file, click "Open with" and indicate the App you prefer (flag for permanent replacement). Windows does all this automatically and without risk.

Comment: The poster may not have access to the machine in a GUI mode and can't right click so have asked for a CMD based solution.

Comment: We answer questions, not ascertain why the asker wants to know. If there's another way to do something, it should be included after an actual answer. If you are not going to answer the question, but give feedback about other answers, make it a comment, not an answer.